# Using mono to call C# from C/C++

Tags: c++, .net, linux, mono

I need to write docx files on Linux so I'm compiling the [Open-XML-SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) with [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). I'm trying to do what [this website](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/#invoking-methods-in-the-cil-universe) suggests.

What can I do to understand why I can't get the MonoMethod* object for the constructor, or better, get this to work?

Here are my sample programs and output:

```
// hello.cs
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
    public Hello(string s) { _s = s; }

    public void DoSomething(string s) { _s = s; }

    public string _s;
    }
}
```

---

```
// hello.cpp
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init("hello.dll");
  MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "hello.dll");
  MonoImage* image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

  MonoClass* helloClass = mono_class_from_name(image, "HelloWorld", "Hello");


  MonoMethodDesc* ctorDesc = mono_method_desc_new("HelloWorld.Hello:Hello(string)", false);
  MonoMethod* ctorMethod = mono_method_desc_search_in_class(ctorDesc, helloClass);

  printf("ctorDesc from mono_method_desc_new() is %p\n", ctorDesc);
  printf("ctorMethod from mono_method_desc_search_in_class() is %p    <----\n", ctorMethod);


  MonoMethodDesc* doDesc = mono_method_desc_new("HelloWorld.Hello:DoSomething(string)", false);
  MonoMethod* doMethod = mono_method_desc_search_in_class(doDesc, helloClass);

  printf("doDesc from mono_method_desc_new() is %p\n", doDesc);
  printf("doMethod from mono_method_desc_search_in_class() is %p\n", doMethod);


  mono_jit_cleanup(domain);
}
```

---

```
$ mcs /nologo /warn:4 /debug:pdbonly /o  /out:hello.dll /target:library hello.cs /reference:WindowsBase.dll
$ gcc hello.cpp -g3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` -o hello
$ ./hello
ctorDesc from mono_method_desc_new() is 0x22b1920
ctorMethod from mono_method_desc_search_in_class() is (nil)    <----
doDesc from mono_method_desc_new() is 0x22b2590
doMethod from mono_method_desc_search_in_class() is 0x224ae38

$ uname -a
Linux U14-OOXML 3.16.0-37-generic #51~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 6 15:23:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried using the real name, `.ctor`, not the fake name that C# uses for its C++-lite syntax?

Comment: Try disassembling the binary to find out the true names.

Comment: There, turned it into a real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the constructor of class `Hello` is `Hello(string)` is a lie told by the C# language, to make it more familiar to C++ and Java programmers.

But the Mono runtime, like the Microsoft .NET CLR, works with compiled code, not C#.  The true name of every instance constructor is `.ctor`, independent of the type name, and `.cctor` for a type initializer (aka "static constructor").  If you search for `.ctor(string)` instead of `Hello(string)`, you should meet with success.  There are some [working](https://forge.gluster.org/uwsgi/uwsgi/blobs/e517bcea7c618241ad58ca981940e8d0ff55b899/plugins/mono/mono_plugin.c) [examples](https://github.com/dodecaphonic/attaching-monkeys/blob/master/src/bridge.cc) online, easier to find once you know what to look for.

Other places where C# lies about names are for default indexers, nested types, closures.... quite a few actually.  In all these cases you can see the true naming convention present in the metadata by using a disassembler (`ildasm` in .NET, not sure about the name of the equivalent Mono tool).

Comment: Can you please help me to solve the situation where I have to call C++ dll from C# using Mono