# How to get class attributes in Mono?

Tags: mono

I want use attributes in C# code which will work in my project which **uses Mono**.
It is possible to get class attributes from Mono runtime? And how, if it is possible?

A little explanation:

This is my class with attribute:

```
[SomeAttribute]
public class SomeClass { /* ... */ }
```

And somewhere in my C++ code I start Mono and load assembly with this class.
In C++ code I want to discover attributes of this `SomeClass` and perform some actions. So how can I do this? Can Mono tell what attributes used in this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to do this from the C++ side, so what you probably want to do is get the attributes as normal from within your C# class:

`typeof(SomeType).GetAttributes()`

And then call a function from your C++ code to actually access that information.

[Using mono to call C# from C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334178/using-mono-to-call-c-sharp-from-c-c)

Comment: Thanks, but I need get attributes from Mono runtime.

Comment: You're not being sufficiently specific about what you're trying to do or what attributes you're after, or why.

Comment: I add explanation of what I want, but I think it's not enough.

Comment: That's completely different from the original question. I've updated my answer.